# Curvature of a curve $\vec{r}(s)=(3+s)\hat{x}+\hat{y}$

Tags: differential-geometry

> I am having problem in calculating the curvature of the following curve.$$ \vec{r}(s)=(3+s)\hat{x}+\hat{y} $$ where $s$ is the arc length parameter.

I know that $$ \kappa=\left|\frac{d\vec{T}}{ds}\right|=\left|\frac{\vec{T}'(t)}{\vec{r}'(t)}\right|=\frac{| \vec{r}'(t)\times \vec{r}''(t) |}{|\vec{r}'(t)|^3} $$ But how to calculate in terms of $s$?

Comment: Same formula. You'd better hope that $|\vec r'(s)|=1$ if $s$ is really an arclength parameter.

Comment: So it will be $\kappa=\frac{| \vec{r}'(s)\times \vec{r}''(s) |}{|\vec{r}'(s)|^3}$

Comment: Sure. The first formula works for *any* parametrization (i.e., *all parametrizations*).

Comment: Then the curvature will be zero as $\vec{r}''(s)=\vec{0}$

Comment: Yes, I am pi. Indeed, this is a parametrization of a horizontal line in the $xy$-plane, and lines don't curve!! :)